# How to call a function in a parent razor component from a child item in blazor?

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to create a templated table component following the example in the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Here I want to add a sorting function to the table:

```
// This is a function in the code-behind of TableTemplate.razor
public void SortSourceList(/*some args*/)
{
    // sort based on given args
}
```

The question is the following. I want this function to be accessible from the children, for example the `TableHeader` items:

```
 @page "/somepage
 <TableTemplate Items="pets" Context="pet">
    <TableHeader>
        <th>
             <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
                 @onclick=<!--call the sorting function from here-->>
        </th>
    </TableHeader>
    <RowTemplate>
        ...
    </RowTemplate>
</TableTemplate>
@code{ // page related code - don't want to handle anything concerning the table here }
```

I know this could be done by passing down the instance of `TableTemplate` as a `CascadingParameter`, but how to get this in a normal html item, which isn't a razor component? Also I don't necessarily want to have to add a `TableTemplate` instance as class property to any child components (which as far as I know is needed to access a cascading parameter?), so I was wondering if one could pass the function or an event directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple direct way by making the TableHeader typed as well.

Changes in **TableTemplate.razor**

```
  <thead>
    <tr>@TableHeader(this)</tr>
  </thead>

@code {
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment<TableTemplate<TItem>>? TableHeader { get; set; }
```

and then use it like

```
<TableTemplate Items="pets" >
  <TableHeader Context="table">

       <button @onclick="() => table.SortSourceList(/* args */)" />

  </TableHeader>

  <RowTemplate Context="pet">
     ...
  </RowTemplate>
</TableTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use EventCallback inside the child component and call the parent function:

Parent

```
<_ChildComponentCall parentFunction="SortSourceList"></_ChildComponent>

public void SortSourceList(/*some args*/)
{
    // sort based on given args
}
```

Child

```
<TableTemplate Items="pets" Context="pet">
    <TableHeader>
        <th>
             <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
                 @onclick="() => parentFunction.InvokeAsync()"
        </th>
    </TableHeader>
    <RowTemplate>
        ...
    </RowTemplate>
</TableTemplate>
@code
[Parameter]
public EventCallback parentFunction { get; set; }
```

After you run the function you can save the sorting data in a service variable, and call that variable from the child.

Comment: `_ChildComponentCall` is a separate razor component?

Comment: No, it is the TableTemplate child component where you'll have the table template and the eventcallback

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I don't have an item called `ChildComponent`, which I could put into `TableTemplate.razor` Other than that, the solution is clear to me, and I'll mark it as solution, even though I was more looking for a solution where no code in the child was needed (more or less somthing like `@onclick=MyParentsFunction` without any handling in the component that uses the table template needed. )

Comment: How do you call the child component from the parent? I know you dont have an item called ChildComponent, that is just a random name because you did not mention how you make that call.

Comment: You can make a direct call from the button like this @onclick="() => parentFunction.InvokeAsync()" i will edit the answer

Comment: Oh, ok I guess now I understand. There is actually no child component. I have a razor page which implements the ` Tabletemplate`  as shown above. `Tabletemplate` looks exactly like in the linked article above. Children are directly the `<th>` and `<td>` items within `FileTableHeader` and `RowTemplate`

Comment: Ok, then i'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. If they are in the same razor component you just have to call the function directly from the @onclick, it dosnt matter that it is a html item. Just call @onclick="SortSourceList" and it will call the function. If that is not what you want I need more explation on what the problem is because it's not clear.

Comment: Yeah sorry for being not 100% clear (I'll edit my question). The problem is that `SortSourceList` is not accessible from my razor page, as it is a function of `TableTemplate`